# How to apply object transformations in Godot UI?

Tags: godot

E.g I have changed the scale and rotation of a `MeshInstance` and I want the editor and GDscripts to accept new settings as scale 1 and rotation 0 degrees in all axes.

Comment: I've never seen a game engine have such a scale/rotation "apply" feature. That's usually something that's handled in the 3D modelling software beforehand. Have you considered creating an empty parent object with scale 1 and 0 rotation, and placing your scaled/rotated MeshInstance as a child of this object, then have your GDscripts refer to the parent? That's how we'd tackle a similar situation in Unity for example.

Comment: @DMGregory That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `MeshInstance` inside of a `Spatial` node. Then place the `MeshInstance` as needed. Then you can manipulate the `Spatial` node.

Furthermore, you can save the `Spatial` node as a scene. The scene will have an internal tree where the `MeshInstance` exists.

Then you can add that scene in another parent scene, and it will appear as a single node, with the fact that is has a `MeshInstance` and that said `MeshInstance` was moved hidden from view.

You can do that to create an scene that has all the nodes you need for your particular game object (eg. `KinematicBoy`/`RigidBody`/`StaticBody`, lights, camera, and so on), and then use it as a single node in scene that represent a stage.